# Curl error: Could not resolve host: www.localhost

Tags: php, curl

I get an error could not resolve `host:www.localhost`. I don't know why it is coming.

```
$url ="http://www.localhost:81/dbWIP/selectApi.php?name=".$name;
$client = curl_init();
echo $client;
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($client,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$response = curl_exec($client);
curl_close($client);
echo $response
$result = json_decode($response);
```

Comment: It probably is just `http://localhost`.

Comment: Have you tried without www?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `www.` in url

Like this

```
$url ="http://localhost:81/dbWIP/selectApi.php?name=".$name;
$client = curl_init();
echo $client;
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($client,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$response = curl_exec($client);
curl_close($client);
echo $response
$result = json_decode($response);
```

and also verify your port number `81`

```
netstat -a -b
```

that's tell you what program is bound to port 81